# How to correctly have contrib.auth in both shared and tenant schemas

Tags: django

I'm trying to build multi-tenants web app using django. I'm using [django-tenant-schema](https://github.com/bernardopires/django-tenant-schemas).
I want to maintain seperate auth table for public schema and tenants schema. I need some suggestions.